# PHP - How to get year, month, day from time string

Tags: php

Given the following timestring:

```
$str = '2000-11-29';

$php_date = getdate( $str );
echo '<pre>';
print_r ($php_date);
echo '</pre>';
```

How to get the year/month/day in PHP?

```
[seconds] => 20
[minutes] => 33
[hours] => 18
[mday] => 31
[wday] => 3
[mon] => 12
[year] => 1969
[yday] => 364
[weekday] => Wednesday
[month] => December
[0] => 2000
```

I don't know why I get 1969 for year.

Thank you

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use [`strtotime`](https://www.php.net/strtotime) to parse a time string, and pass the resulting timestamp to [`getdate`](https://www.php.net/getdate) (or use [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to format your time).

```
$str = '2000-11-29';

if (($timestamp = strtotime($str)) !== false)
{
  $php_date = getdate($timestamp);
  // or if you want to output a date in year/month/day format:
  $date = date("Y/m/d", $timestamp); // see the date manual page for format options      
}
else
{
  echo 'invalid timestamp!';
}
```

Note that `strtotime` will return `false` if the time string is invalid or can't be parsed. When the timestamp you're trying to parse is invalid, you end up with the 1969-12-31 date you encountered before.

Answer (score 23):

PHP - How to get year, month, day from time string

```
$dateValue = strtotime($q);                     

$yr = date("Y", $dateValue) ." "; 
$mon = date("m", $dateValue)." "; 
$date = date("d", $dateValue);
```

Comment: its a code practice to explain the answer also so that future readers can be benefitted

Answer (score 12):

Update: Forgot to add semicolon at end of first line, try this:

```
<?php       
$str = "2010-08-29"; // Missed semicolon here
$time = strtotime($str);

// You can now use date() functions with $time, like
$weekday = date("l", $time); // Wednesday or whatever date it is    
?>
```

Hopefully that will get you going!

Answer (score 3):

Using the object-oriented programming style, you can do this with **[DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)**

```
$dateFormat = 'Y-m-d';
$stringDate = '2000-11-29';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat($dateFormat, $stringDate);
```

Then, you can decompose your date using the **[format()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)** method

```
$year = $date->format('Y'); // returns a string
```

If you prefer the numeric format, instead of the string format, you can use the **[intval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)** function

```
$year = intval($date->format('Y')); // returns an integer
```

Here some formats that you can use

- `Y` A full numeric representation of a year, 4 digits
- `m` Month of the year, 2 digits with leading zeros
- `d` Day of the month, 2 digits with leading zeros
- `H` 24-hour format of an hour, 2 digits with leading zeros
- `i` Minutes, 2 digits with leading zeros
- `s` Seconds, 2 digits with leading zeros

Here the entire list of the formats that you can use : http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score -2):

PHP - we can get year, month, day from time string in many formats.

```
$dateFromDb = '2021-2-6 13:15:19';

if (($timestamp = strtotime($dateFromDb)) !== false) {
    // auto format full time
    $php_date = getdate($timestamp);
    echo '<br>';
    foreach($php_date as $key =>$value){
        echo $key.'='.$value.'<br>';
    }

    // manually format time
    echo'-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-<br>';
    echo '4 digit year =            '.date("Y", $timestamp).'<br>';
    echo '2 digit year =            '.date("y", $timestamp).'<br>';
    echo 'Month =                   '.date("m", $timestamp).'<br>';
    echo 'Day =                     '.date("d", $timestamp).'<br>';
    echo 'Time in 24 Hours Format = '.date("H", $timestamp).'<br>';
    echo 'Time in 12 Hours Format = '.date("h", $timestamp).'<br>';
    echo 'Minutes =                 '.date("i", $timestamp).'<br>';
    echo 'Seconds =                 '.date("s", $timestamp).'<br>';
    echo '-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_- <br>';
    // and we can combine format also.
    // and we can add '/' or ':' between year,month,days or anything we want.
    echo 'Time =  ' .date("H:i:s" ,$timestamp).'<br>';
    echo 'Date =  ' .date("d/m/Y" ,$timestamp).'<br>';

    } else {
        echo 'invalid date format.';
    }
```

Comment: The accepted answer already advises the use 9f `strtotime()`.  The OP is not asking how to use different formats with `date()`.  Please do not needlessly bloat old pages.